How to prevent swiper from clicking content when reached last swiper slide button?
Let me explain better, when we are pressing next or prev, it always reach to one button that be grayed out, meaning we can't move anymore forward when it is next button, or backwards when it is prev button, but there is one problem, when I reached to this grayed out button, if I click on it, it actually clicks on the content of slide, leading to the respective route of that slide.
I want to prevent this behavior, I don't want in any way that the user could click on content by clicking on the buttons even if they are grayed out, how can I prevent this from happening, is there any option?
This is my current component:
<swiper-container
        className='collection-wrapper'
        slides-per-view='auto'
        navigation={true}
        space-between={25}
        grab-cursor={true}
       
      >
        {collectionState?.map(({ id, name, description, image }) => {
          return (
            <swiper-slide
              key={id}
              className='collection-wrapper-list'
            >
              <NavLink to='/new'>
                <div className='background-fill'></div>
                <div className='collection-wrapper-text'>
                  <StyledHeadings as='h3' className='collection-text'>
                    {name}
                  </StyledHeadings>
                  <StyledParagraphs $size='p1' className='collection-text'>
                    {description}
                  </StyledParagraphs>
                </div>
                <div className='collection-wrapper-image'>
                  <img className='collection-image' src={image} />
                </div>
              </NavLink>
            </swiper-slide>
          );
        })}
      </swiper-container>

Don't mind the NavLink there, it is just for testing purposes.
As you can see I am using swiper elements as it was recommended by Swiper itself for using along with React from now on as Swiper for React will be disabled.

Add an event listener to the Swiper navigation buttons.
Stop the propagation of click events if the buttons are disabled.
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';
import Swiper from 'swiper/bundle';
import 'swiper/css/bundle';

const CollectionComponent = ({ collectionState }) => {

  useEffect(() => {
    const swiper = new Swiper('.collection-wrapper', {
      slidesPerView: 'auto',
      spaceBetween: 25,
      grabCursor: true,
      navigation: {
        nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
        prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
      },
    });

    const nextButton = document.querySelector('.swiper-button-next');
    const prevButton = document.querySelector('.swiper-button-prev');

    const handleClick = (e) => {
      if (e.target.classList.contains('swiper-button-disabled')) {
        e.stopPropagation();
      }
    };

    if (nextButton) {
      nextButton.addEventListener('click', handleClick);
    }

    if (prevButton) {
      prevButton.addEventListener('click', handleClick);
    }

    return () => {
      if (nextButton) {
        nextButton.removeEventListener('click', handleClick);
      }

      if (prevButton) {
        prevButton.removeEventListener('click', handleClick);
      }
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <swiper-container
      className='collection-wrapper'
      slides-per-view='auto'
      navigation={true}
      space-between={25}
      grab-cursor={true}
    >
      {collectionState?.map(({ id, name, description, image }) => {
        return (
          <swiper-slide
            key={id}
            className='collection-wrapper-list'
          >
            <NavLink to='/new'>
              <div className='background-fill'></div>
              <div className='collection-wrapper-text'>
                <StyledHeadings as='h3' className='collection-text'>
                  {name}
                </StyledHeadings>
                <StyledParagraphs $size='p1' className='collection-text'>
                  {description}
                </StyledParagraphs>
              </div>
              <div className='collection-wrapper-image'>
                <img className='collection-image' src={image} />
              </div>
            </NavLink>
          </swiper-slide>
        );
      })}
    </swiper-container>
  );
};

export default CollectionComponent;


Hi, thank you for your answer. I tried to implement what you presented but there is one problem and it is with swiper element/web components, it simply is horrible in finding the items by their classes, I don't know why, when I write my css, I have to come up with things like swiper-container::part(element_here), they implemented things in such a hidden way, that we have to access them through sub selectors... Unfortunately with approach by classes I couldn't reach to the result because it doesn't even find the existence of the button.

I could find the button through this code: const nextButton = document.querySelector('swiper-container')?.shadowRoot?.querySelector("div")?.querySelector(".swiper-button-next"), but this is one of the ugliest things I've seen in my life, they've hidden the buttons and other elements inside of a shadowRoot, I don't know if this is the best way to find the button, but it was the way I could do it.

The code is working except it has the same behavior, when I click on the disabled button, it reacts to the container underneath and leads me to the route defined.

After running into the same problem, I noticed swiper adds css that removes the pointer events when the button is disabled. So simply adding pointer-events auto to swiper button disabled selector should do the trick.
.swiper-button-next.swiper-button-disabled {
  opacity: 0.4 !important;
  pointer-events: auto !important;
}

